# Reference for Technical drawing

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I am looking for some textbook about underlying mathematics of technical drawing. What I mean by ''underlying'' here is that, in technical drawing, we use a lot of things in geometry such as parallel/orthogonal projections, coordinates... However I read several books about technical drawing and found that no ones of them give a complete mathematics prerequisite.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Search for "Descriptive Geometry".

Comment: I don't know if it's what I'm looking for, but you might be interested "Thinking, Drawing, Modelling"

Comment: @JohnDouma it's too general for me, but anw, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LuisAlexandher thanks, I had a look at your reference and found that it's at a higher level than I expected. I would like to find some reference which is more elementary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a collection of older books that you can browse through .. perhaps you will find one that has the material you are looking for  https://archive.org/search.php?query=descriptive%20geometry.